# install mysql-dev on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mysql

I was requested to install mysql-dev on ubuntu 18.04 , but I couldn't find such package.I only got mysql-server.

is there a way to install mysql-dev , and how does it differ from mysql-server?

Answer (score 14):

There's no mysql-dev package, but libmysqlclient-dev.

You should run in your terminal:

```
sudo apt install libmysqlclient-dev
```